# Android Firebase listeners never fires

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have OnFailure and OnSuccess listeners to a get call in FireBase, with my FireBase permissions set allow to all (for debug). However, none of these listeners are ever fired. The user is authenticated successfully as well. Here's the code:

```
 Globals.db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference user = null;
    if (!Globals.testMode)
    user = Globals.db.collection("users").document(email.getText().toString());
    else user = Globals.db.collection("users").document(Globals.testEmail);
    System.out.println("DebugMode01: " + Globals.fireAuth.toString());


if (Globals.fireAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
    System.out.printf("The user instance is correct.");
}



    user.get().addOnSuccessListener(userDocument -> {
        Globals.initUser((String)userDocument.get("email"),(String)userDocument.get("fname"), (String)userDocument.get("lname"));
        warning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Globals.endLoad();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }).addOnFailureListener( x -> {
        Globals.endLoad();
        warning.setText("Invalid error instance with the server.");
        warning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }).addOnCanceledListener(() -> {
        warning.setText("This process was cancelled.");
        Globals.endLoad();
        warning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });
```

Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure that your device is connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes. The Auth functions work. Also, there is an onFailure listener.

Comment: Have you tried to simply log something and not set a text to a view?